# Expanding fractions

Tags: calculus

This seems like a simple question, but I can't solve it

Expand the fraction

$$\frac{s+1}{s+2}$$

Mathematica says it is $1-\frac{1}{s+2}$

But how?

Take

$$\frac{s+1}{s+2}=\frac{s}{s+2}+\frac{1}{s+2}$$

But then, how do you simplify further?

Thanks

Comment: I mean no offence, but I do find it surprising based on your profile that you didn't know this. That said, sometimes I also ask questions that surprise people and then I realise I should have known the answer much earlier. This probably happens to most people. Anyway, this is an important "trick" that is used in many settings: integration is one that comes to mind (as integrating $\int\frac{s+1}{s+2}ds\ $ by parts is longer than integrating $\int 1 - \frac{1}{s+2}ds\ $ directly) ; convergence of sequences is another.

Comment: Since your "how?" cannot mean "what did Mathematica *think*, how did it *find*?", a sensible though unexpected answer would be: just check it is correct. But a more useful one is the following general trick: substitute $t=$ the denominator, and see what the numerator becomes.

Comment: Don't they teach this in primary school with colors?

Comment: Good point Anne! Thanks again.

Comment: @BobDobbs I was daydreaming most of the time in primary school. Therefore I ask 40 years later.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Daydreaming what? Wolfs or sheep?:)

Comment: @BobDobbs the teacher, women in general and the fellow girls in the class. A  major distraction to mathematics.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Rainbow...

Comment: @BobDobbs WOMEN, not rainbow.

Comment: @BobDobbs I think you misunderstood the language since you are not native English. "Fellow girls" is not boys and girls. It means the girls that are your fellow students. Haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{s+1}{s+2} =\frac{(s+2)-1}{s+2}=\frac{s+2}{s+2}-\frac{1}{s+2}.$$

You can also do long division of polynomials.  The quotient is $1$ and the remainder is $1$.

Comment: What can I say to this answer and that logo: CHEERS

Answer (score 2):

The way to proceed is to add and subtract the same quantity at the numerator:

$\frac{s+1}{s+2}=\frac{s+1+(1-1)}{s+2}=\frac{s+2-1}{s+2}=\frac{s+2}{s+2}-\frac{1}{s+2}=1-\frac{1}{s+2}$

The procedure is justified by the fact that the two addends (1 and -1) cancel each other out and therefore the numerator remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{array}{rr|l}
&s+1 & s+2\\
&s+2  &  \\
\hline &\text{(Remiander)}\color{lime}{-1}&\color{purple}{1} \text{(Quotient)}
\end{array}
Hence,
$$\frac{s+1}{s+2}=\color{purple}{1}+\frac{\color{lime}{-1}}{s+2}=1-\frac{1}{s+2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is more visible on substituting $x=s+2$ (hopefully it is legal in elementary school math course). Then
$${s+1\over s+2}={x-1\over x}$$
Now it is  hard to resist from dividing each term in the numerator by $x.$
$${x-1\over x}=1-{1\over x}=1-{1\over s+2}$$